# Problem developing a turn-based battle system

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I have recently got into coding and I am currently developing a small turn-based RPG, but I have encountered some real issue with the battle system. I am still learning and I never thought about asking questions here. Anyway, after getting many things done correctly, I have encountered this issue where using the defend command rises the player hp for some reason. Here is the code:

```
import random
import sys
import os
class Entity():
    def __init__(self, hp, atk, dif):
        self.hp = hp
        self.atk = atk
        self.dif = dif

class Battle():

    def Attack(self, attacker, defender):
        damage = attacker.atk - defender.dif
        defender.hp -= damage

    def Combat(self, player, enemy):
        turns = []
        while True:
            while len(turns) < 5:
                turn = random.randint(1, 2)
                if turn == 1:
                    turns.append("player")
                else:
                    turns.append("enemy")

            for current_turn in turns:
                print(player.hp, enemy.hp)
                if current_turn == "player":
                    print(f"TURNS: \n{current_turn}\n{turns[turns.index(current_turn)+ 1:]}")
                    choice = input("1. Attack\n2. Defend\n")
                    if choice == "1":
                        self.Attack(player, enemy)
                        player.dif = 20
                    elif choice == "2":
                        player.dif *= 2
                    else:
                        print("Lost your chance!")
                elif current_turn == "enemy":
                    print("Enemy turn!")
                    print(f"Next turns are: {turns}")
                    enemy_choice = random.randint(1, 2)
                    if enemy_choice == 2:
                        print("He attacks you!")
                        self.Attack(enemy, player)
                        enemy.dif = 0
                    else:
                        print("He defends himself.")
                        enemy.dif = 10
                os.system("clear")
                turns.pop(0)
                if player.hp <= 0:
                    print("You died!")
                    sys.exit(0)
                elif enemy.hp <= 0:
                    print("YOU WON!")
                    sys.exit(0)
                break




charachter = Entity(100, 15, 15)
boss = Entity(300, 40, 0)
testbattle = Battle()
testbattle.Combat(charachter, boss)
```

Comment: do you mean the attack method? If the damage is negative (dif is greater than attack) then the subtraction is converted to an addition making the enemy's hp get higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Battle.Attack` method:

```
def Attack(self, attacker, defender):
        damage = attacker.atk - defender.dif
        defender.hp -= damage
```

If `attacker.atk - defender.dif` is a negative number, then you'll be subtracting a negative number from `defender.hp`, increasing it.

If I'm the player, and my defense starts out as `15`, and then I defend, my defense will become `30` because of `player.dif *= 2`. If I defend again the next turn, my defense will be `60`, which is greater than the boss' attack of `40`. So, if the boss then attacks me in `Battle.Attack`, we would get `damage = 40 - 60`, which is `damage = -20`, effectively healing the player by twenty points.

Comment: As a solution, you could fix this by changing the line to `damage = max(attacker.atk - defender.dif, 0)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I managed to do it by simply re-adjusting player.dif to 15 when he defends himself and then double it as before.

Answer (score 0):

The entity will be healed if the attackers attack value is less than the defender's defence value. Perhaps instead of subtracting the 2 values you could use a defence divisor/ multiplier